# What is the purpose of ANYSIZE_ARRAY in <winnt.h>?

Tags: winapi, dynamic-arrays

What's the purpose of `ANYSIZE_ARRAY`, located in WinNT.h?

I see an MSDN blog post about it from 2004 but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Please give us link to MSDN blog post?

Comment: @Agnel http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are talking about [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120209061713/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx).

It is often used when a variable-sized (unknown at compile time) array is part of a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int CommonFlags
    int CountOfThings;
    THING Things[ANYSIZE_ARRAY]; //Things[1];
} THINGSANDFLAGS;
```

To work with those structures you often first call the desired API to get the size of the data, then allocate a block of memory big enough and finally call the same API again so it can fill in the data...

Comment: @LemonBeagle A linked list requires more memory and/or the API implementation might already have the items in a array internally and can just memcpy it into the callers buffer. It is also slower to walk the list of items and you have to free each item and not just a big buffer...

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](http://www.cs.uofs.edu/~beidler/Ada/win32/win32.html):

> In C, a variable-size array is declared as `a[1]` or `a[ANYSIZE_ARRAY]`, where `ANYSIZE_ARRAY` is defined as `1`. Then it is used as if it were bigger.