# Who is responsible for deleting FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION.FileName?

Tags: c++, winapi, readdirectorychangesw

Winapi's `ReadDirectoryChanges` uses `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` to present it's results. The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct _FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION {
  DWORD NextEntryOffset;
  DWORD Action;
  DWORD FileNameLength;
  WCHAR FileName[1];
} FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION, *PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION;
```

If I get this struct filled by winapi, how do I correctly delete the `FileName` `WCHAR*`? Do I have to delete it?

None of the examples (not that there are many examples) of the `ReadDirectoryChanges` mention deleting anything. Microsoft of course does not provide any examples at all.

Comment: There is nothing to delete. It is all part of the `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` object. You should read about [ANYSIZE_ARRAY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9195889).

Comment: There are MS samples in SDK and old VC samples. SDK :  [Service.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/WebServicesDevicesApi/FileService/cpp/FileServiceService/Service.cpp):

Comment: This is documented. In the docs for ReadDirectoryChanges.

Comment: The `FileName` member doesn't have pointer type. It's an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`malloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloc?view=vs-2019) you need call [`free`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/free?view=vs-2019) after you finish using the object.

For example:

```
DWORD FileNameLength = 100;
PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION file_notify_info = (PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION)malloc(FIELD_OFFSET(FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION, FileName[FileNameLength]));

free(file_notify_info);
```

Refer to "[Why do some structures end with an array of size 1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=38043)".